# Android: setselector color for listview not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview activity in which I set the selector color using the following code. But when I select an item, the whole list gets highlighted with the selector color, which I don't want. Where Am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
lv.setSelector(R.color.blue);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this way to use Selector
Create a xml in `res/drawable` and set the color for different [event state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)
Then this xml as Selector
For example, let `res/drawable/selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"   
    android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

Then declare gray in `your res\values\colors.xml`

```
<color name="gray">#808080</color>
```

Then set selector as

```
lv.setSelector( R.drawable.selector);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Labeeb. But I get the error in xml         Error: Color types not allowed (at 'drawable' with value '#808080').

Comment: Thanks Labeeb. I followed everything. But I don't see any selector. No selector is visible. What should I do?

Comment: These is the way i used. Try by removing that setBackgroundColor

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to make res/drawable/selector.xml.
Just add these lines in your onCreate method:

```
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(R.color.pressed_state_color));
selector.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(R.color.normal_state_color));
lv.setSelector(selector);
```

Sorry, I haven't enough reputation to add comments to previous answers.

Comment: what does it mean by {-android.R.attr.state_pressed} ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your example, it worked better for me this way...Try this instead. 
Create a xml in `res/drawable` and set the color for different [event state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Then this xml as Selector
For example, let `res/drawable/selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

Then declare gray in your `res\values\strings.xml`

```
<color name="gray">#808080</color>
```

Then set selector as

```
lv.setSelector( R.drawable.selector);
lv.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true); // if you have background Drawable on your listView
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set

```
android:state_selected = "true"
```

to

```
android:state_selected = "false"
```

Comment: When I do this with the code in the above answer, the entire ListView lights up with the specified color instead of the single row I am selecting

Answer (score 0):

Answers here doesn't work for custom views in ListView because of invalid background. Solution is to set the background of each item to `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`. Here is example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

      <!-- your item content-->
   </LinearLayout>
```

After that, StateListDrawable works as expected.

Source: http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html,