# Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/dark.xml from drawable resource

Tags: android

`Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/dark.xml from drawable resource`

I have that error. I tried clean project. I can see "dark" in "R" file. I can use it in project: I mean autocomplete working well, but when I turn on app on emulator there is this error. There is how I use it:

```
songList.setSelector(R.color.dark);
```

Comment: you need to include the dark.xml in the drawable folder

Comment: `#setSelector(int)` takes a drawable, i.e. something from `R.drawable.yourdrawablenamegoeshere`. Make a shape drawable or color drawable in a suitable `res/drawable` & it should work a tad bit better.

Comment: A similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020222/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-for-ic-sync-black-24dp-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use `setSelector()` is:

Create a xml in res/drawable

For example, let `res/drawable/selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"   
    android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Then declare black in your `res\values\strings.xml`

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Then set selector as

```
songList.setSelector( R.drawable.selector);
```

Note: Answer ideas taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342405/android-setselector-color-for-listview-not-working) post.

EDIT:
Try cleaning your project in Eclipse and re-starting Eclipse.

Comment: I did it and still have this same error, but with "res\drawable\dark.xml"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
       <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#444"/>
       <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#444"/>
       <item android:color="#ccc"/>
    </selector>

Comment: According to the Official Android developers guide, you can and should put the selector element xml in the `res/color/` directory not in `res/drawable/` directory.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: @ChaitanyaBhardwaj and people downvoting the answer. this was answered *5 years ago* when selectors were in drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your drawable resource in the res/color folder. You should be putting that in the res/drawable folder.