# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException for ic_sync_black_24dp.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I've struggled with this for over a week, because I figure it has to be something with my environment, but I can't narrow it down.

I start an empty project, add a single "Blank" activity and accept all defaults.  After the project finishes setting up, I add a "Settings" activity.

Inside MainActivity.java, I add two lines of code to connect the two activities, and then build the project.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I send the application to debug, and when I pick "Settings" on the action bar, the application crashes with:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020049
```

I get this same error on the virtual images, and when I send the APK to a real physical device and try to view the settings activity.

I've started new and clean projects several times, and I get the same result with each project.  I've tried clean builds, I've tried deleting the R.java stuff.  When I look at the res/drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp.xml in my project (which was created by the add new activity wizard) I can see the icon and everything looks normal.

If I remove the one line from the pref_headers.xml file that specifies this icon, the project builds fine, and the settings activity has icons for the other two choices, but not the ic_sync_black_24dp.xml icon.

Here's the line I have to manually delete from pref_headers.xml:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp"
```

So this is the valid pref_headers.xml file for me:

```
<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->

<header
    android:fragment="com.schramauto.anothertrial.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />

<header
    android:fragment="com.schramauto.anothertrial.SettingsActivity$NotificationPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_notifications" />

<header
    android:fragment="com.schramauto.anothertrial.SettingsActivity$DataSyncPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_data_sync" />
```

In res\drawable, there are a 3 xml files added by the wizard that added the settings activity.  All 3 display properly for me and show a valid preview of an icon.

Here is the contents of the "good" xml, ic_info_black_24dp.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zm1,15h-2v-6h2v6zm0,-8h-2V7h2v2z" />
</vector>
```

Here is the questionable XML (ic_sync_black_24dp.xml):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24.0dp"
    android:height="24.0dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12 4V1L8 5l4 4V6c3.31 0 6 2.69 6 6 0 1.01,-.25 1.97,-.7 2.8l1.46 1.46C19.54 15.03 20 13.57 20 12c0,-4.42,-3.58,-8,-8,-8zm0 14c-3.31 0,-6,-2.69,-6,-6 0,-1.01.25,-1.97.7,-2.8L5.24 7.74C4.46 8.97 4 10.43 4 12c0 4.42 3.58 8 8 8v3l4,-4,-4,-4v3z" />
</vector>
```

Again, I've tried this maybe 15 times (creating brand new projects and connecting the two activities), rebooted, searched google, searched here, and I can't figure out what's wrong with ic_sync_black_24dp.xml that the wizard put in my project.

Since I'm making an assumption that this may be environmental in my IDE or my local build configuration, here are some high level details on my setup:
Windows 10, Android Studio 1.5, JRE 1.8.0

Comment: Where is ic_sync_black_24dp file located ?

Comment: Have you tried to just rename it?

Comment: I followed your steps to recreate this on my setup and it didn't cause any problem. Android Studio 1.5 on Mac. The only instantly clear difference between the working and non-working Drawables is that the width and height in the non-working one is set as "24.0dp" rather than just "24dp" as in the others, though as I say, that doesn't cause an issue on my setup.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary - That was the clue!  I changed the 24.0 to 24, and now it doesn't crash!  I have no idea why that would be a platform dependent issues that I would build differently on your configuration vs mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that the issue lay with API 21, the 24.0dp that was mentioned did not solve the issue for me instead I was receiving:

```
E/PathParser: error in parsing "c-3.31 0,-6,-2.69,-6,-6 0,-1.01.25,-1.97.7,-2.8"
```

I found the answer at https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/225

It turns out the pathData is invalid cannot be parsed in API 21 properly (the problem does not exist in API 22 or 23).
Simply replace the pathData with:

```
android:pathData="M12 4V1L8 5l4 4V6c3.31 0 6 2.69 6 6 0 1.01,-.25 1.97,-.7 2.8l1.46 1.46C19.54 15.03 20 13.57 20 12c0,-4.42,-3.58,-8,-8,-8zm0 14c-3.31 0,-6,-2.69,-6,-6 0,-1.01 .25,-1.97 .7,-2.8L5.24 7.74C4.46 8.97 4 10.43 4 12c0 4.42 3.58 8 8 8v3l4,-4,-4,-4v3z"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still see this issue on my phone and other similar phones.  Removing the icon fixes it, but I prefer your fix.

Answer (score 2):

Lewis noticed the clue that help me resolve the issue.  I changed the 24.0 to 24

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
```

And now the code executes without error!  Thanks Lewis!

Comment: What is the Android version of your device? I encountered the same problem on Android 5 device but the Android 6 device works fine with the same configuration!

Comment: I'm confused about it, I just put down the patch for Android Studio, and now the issue is back, regardless of if I put in 24dp or 24.0dp.  But if I simply remove the reference completely it's ok.  It's just that one stupid XML.

My virtual devices I've tested on were 5.0.1 with google services and 6.0.  My actual phones were 5.0 and 5.1 -- all exhibit the same failure.

I'm not glad that you're seeing the issue, but I am glad that someone can reproduce it.  Hopefully we can figure out what's really going on with it.

Comment: I checked the exception message and it showed some values are wrong in the android:pathData string, not just the 24.0dp but it works fine on an Android Marshmallow device. Then I tried other activities and fortunately, other activities like the navigation drawer works. So the workaround is to avoid using the Settings activity on Android 5 devices.

Comment: To be clear, I mean to avoid adding a new Settings Activity from the menu/wizard but by hand and it works around the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be your setting for you "Target SDK". Default behaviour may be setting Android 6. Set it for Android 5.0.1 (21), and ensure you have downloaded the SDK from the SDK Manager. You've probably created the settings activity using the wizard before doing this, so you should delete the settings activity, make sure you have the appropriate SDK and project settings, and re-create it.

Comment: In my case, I was starting brand new projects each time, and even in a new/clean project I was seeing this behavior.  It wasn't an "old" settings activity.