# Error adding custom theme to app

Tags: android, xml, themes, background-color

I added the following theme to my app with a background color of white.But I get the following  error and I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

`Error: Color types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '#FF0000')`.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> 
  <item name="android:windowBackground">#FF0000</item>
 </style>
```

And referenced the theme in mymanifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342405/android-setselector-color-for-listview-not-working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Android Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) page, you have to use a separate color resource to set the color.

> (Note that the color needs to supplied as a separate resource here
>   because the android:windowBackground attribute only supports a
>   reference to another resource; unlike android:colorBackground, it can
>   not be given a color literal.)

For example

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
```

Comment: Thanks,Where would I define the custom color to reference in the windowBackground?

Comment: Create a color.xml file under 'values' and then set it there. You list colors the same as strings, `<color name="custom_theme_background">#ff0000</color>`

Comment: I got a new error when I declared the custom color in the windowBackground code. 'error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@color/custom_theme_color').'

Comment: Ah, that'll most likely be because the names don't match. Either change the windowBackground to custom_theme_background or your color declaration to custom_theme_color

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> 
  <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job,but the background color is still the same after changing color code.Is it possible I have to override the original theme?

Comment: You are already overriding Theme.Light with the parent statment