# Changing Android action bar background colour

Tags: android, xml

For some reason this setup just gives me the default action bar background colour.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#d73830</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
</application>
```

In **activity_main.xml** my theme is set to 'AppTheme'.

Comment: Are you using appcompat v21 or earlier? If it's appcompat v21 you need to define the primary color of your app and it will be used for the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong parent of MyActionBar.
It must be from AppCompat, like next:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using that code I get the error: `Error:(10, 63) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@color/red').` If I replace them with hex values I get: `Error:(10, 63) Color types not allowed (at 'background' with value '#d73830').`

Comment: Extract your color to color.xml. And use reference to it. More you can read there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524654/error-adding-custom-theme-to-app

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use hash code of colour.Here is how.Go to this web page

> http://www.color-hex.com
>   Choose a colour you wish and after copy the code of that colour and later paste into your background section.In general lets say you want your background colour of your screen to be red so you must declare it in xml layout file like this

```
android:background = "#FF0508"/>
```

You can declare this code almost everywhere where you want to change exact things colour and for my opinion its the easiest way.Why not?you got a webpage where you can get colour code and you can use it with a single line everywhere.Delicios isn't it?