# Can't highlight selected item in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm having trouble highlighting the selected entry in a ListView.  I've followed the procedures in http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html.  I've also tried the suggestions in [Android: setselector color for listview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342405/android-setselector-color-for-listview-not-working) to no avail.  I've tried working with a ListView in a DialogFragment as well as in an Activity.

What I've noticed is that (1) I can set the Selection, but I can't query the SelectedItemPosition, (2) onItemSelected never gets called, and (3) I can't get the child View.

Here's some code:

```
public class ChooseDirActivity extends Activity
{
  private ListView listView = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
  {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.choose_dir_layout );
    listView = (ListView)findViewById( R.id.directory_list );
    StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
    selector.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, new ColorDrawable( 0x808080 ));
    selector.addState( new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_selected }, new ColorDrawable( 0xFFFFFF ) );
    listView.setSelector( selector );

    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l )
      {
        Log.i( "myApp",  "onItemSelected" );  // Never called
        view.setBackgroundColor( 0x808080 );
      }

      @Override public void onNothingSelected( AdapterView<?> adapterView ) { } } ); listView.setChoiceMode( ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE ); }

  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    currentDirectory = Intonia.getStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList<String> dirList = getDirectoryList();
    int selected = 11;
    listView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dirList ) );
    Log.i( "myApp",  "setting selection to " + selected );
    listView.setSelection( selected );
    listView.setItemChecked( selected, true );
    Log.i( "myApp",  "selected item position is " + listView.getSelectedItemPosition() );
    View childView = listView.getChildAt( selected );
    if ( childView == null )
    {
      Log.i( "myApp",  "view at " + selected + " is null" );
    }
    else
      childView.setBackgroundColor( 0x808080  );
    Object so = listView.getItemAtPosition( selected );
    Log.i( "myApp",  "item at " + selected + " is " + ( so == null ? "null" : so.getClass().toString() ) );
  }

}
```

Setting the selection *does* move the selected item to the top of the screen, but there doesn't appear to be any way to follow up on it.

This produces the following log output

> ```
> myApp: setting selection to 11
> myApp: selected item position is -1
> myApp: view at 11 is null
> myApp: item at 11 is class java.lang.String
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a ListActivity, and to set the background color by overriding getView in the Adapter.  Setting the selection will move the selected item to the top of the user's screen, but it's useless in providing a view.

```
public class DCListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private int selected = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        ArrayList<String> dirList = getDirectoryList();
        selected = 11;
        setListAdapter( new MyAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dirList ) );
        getListView().setSelection( selected );
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        public MyAdapter( Context context, int resource, List<String> objects )
        {
            super( context, resource, objects );
        }

        @Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
        {
            View v = super.getView( position, convertView, parent );
            if ( position == selected )
                v.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.background_highlight ) );
            else
                v.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.background ) );
            return v;
        }
    }
```

C